# Sqlite sorting by date column

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am storing date in ISO8601 format example 2015-04-15T10:54:14Z in sqlite table, I want youngest date from table. below are the dates in my sqlite table

```
2015-04-15T10:54:14Z 
2015-04-15T10:54:115Z
2015-04-15T10:54:216Z
2015-04-15T10:54:320Z
2015-04-15T10:54:422Z
```

I am trying below query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY datetime("date_column") DESC ;
```

but I am not getting appropriate result.

Comment: Your query is correct and you do need the `datetime` function, because ISO8601 strings are NOT in lexicographic order. They can include a variable amount of characters for the fractions of a second plus a time zone. BUT your date strings are NOT ISO8601 formatted. `10:43:115` is not a valid time (115 seconds?). For fractions of a second you need a dot like: `10:43:11.5`. I know this is old, but it might help someone who stumbles over this.

Answer (score 12):

ISO 8601 datetime stamps normalized to UTC have the nice property that the alphabetical (lexicographic) order is also temporal order.

You don't need the `datetime()`, you can just `ORDER BY date_column DESC` to sort them newest first, and you can add `LIMIT 1` to get just the newest one.

Comment: Don't know why this was down voted. This is real useful information. And it works like a charm since I just implemented it. No mocking with Compartors. Thank you @IaaIto

Comment: "ISO 8601 datetime stamps have the nice property that the alphabetical (lexicographic) order is also temporal order." Only if date and time are giving in UTC without a timezone offset at the end.

Comment: @balu Yes you're right, thanks. Clarified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Update your query to this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY date_column DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @user3271351 Can you mark this as official answer please?

Answer (score 0):

use this method to put date column in your db:

```
public String getDatetime(){
    //get time and date
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", c.getTime());

    //convert it to string array

    return s.toString();
}
```

then use your query as you used before, cause datetime() accepts specific formatts.